# Questions regarding use of Twitter-Oauth API in php

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

Recently I read a nice tutorial [How to Authenticate Users With Twitter OAuth](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/) even it written before changing twitter ID format but it works with the new Twitter ID Format too.

I have some questions , please explain if anybody done it successfully..

- Why we always call two method `getRequestToken` and  `getAccessToken`  ? Is it to get `access token` and `access token secret` ? but both are already given  at below page...

  http://dev.twitter.com/apps/{your_app_id}/my_token.

  what is the exactly need of **request token** and **request token secret**?? although i notice that both token comes different each time we process.
- if we update our status from below method

  `$connection->post( 'statuses/update', array('status' => 'some message got from text area value' );`

Then how do we verify that status has been updated successfully?? It means if i want to display alert message `post has been sent successfully`, how do i implement that in our PHP page??

- which callback URL is important, i.e. where actually user is navigated after posting or doing stuff on twitter?

  1. is it the URL `Registered OAuth Callback URL` which is written at the time of developing an application on

     `http://dev.twitter.com/apps/{id_no}`
     *or*
  2. is it the URL which is defined in our php code (`config.php`) like

     `define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://www.xyz.com');`

  #### one more Q'n
- How to handle deny the access of applications?
  ***Note:*** Please refer my [Question regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782351/how-to-sent-user-back-to-our-website-if-he-deny-twitter-application-to-access)

#### update for @Thai

i did below according to your suggestion

```
$user_info = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$status_info =$connection->get('statuses/show/', array('id' =>32320907720523776) );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($status_info);

echo "</pre> Content : <pre>";
print_r($user_info);
```

returns below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [request] => /1/statuses/show.json?id=3.2320907720524E%2B16&oauth_consumer_key=jashak..&oauth_nonce=bec...&oauth_signature=%2FMj%2B0Z7oyYNKdMn%2B%2FOJ6Ba8ccfo%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1296541384&oauth_token=223961574-cW4...&oauth_version=1.0a
    [error] => No status found with that ID.
)
```

*note:* i hide the `oauth_consumer key`,`oauth_nonce` and `oauth_token` for security purpose ;)

```
Content:
stdClass Object
(
    [follow_request_sent] => 
    [profile_link_color] => 038543
    [profile_image_url] => http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1215444646/minialist-photography-9_normal.jpg
    [contributors_enabled] => 
    [favourites_count] => 31
    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => EEEEEE
    [id_str] => 223961574 // this is also id_str
    [status] => stdClass Object
        (
            [retweeted] => 
            [id_str] => 32320907720523776 // this id_str i used
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [geo] => 
            [contributors] => 
            [source] => Black Noise
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [retweet_count] => 0
            [truncated] => 
            [coordinates] => 
            [created_at] => Tue Feb 01 06:14:39 +0000 2011
            [favorited] => 
            [text] => Twitter test: verify that status has been updated
            [place] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [id] => 3.2320907720524E+16
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
        )
   [screen_name] => ltweetl
   [profile_use_background_image] => 1
   ....
   ...
```

i got error `No status found with that ID` and which `id_str` u r mentioning??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is not specifically for Abraham's Twitter-OAuth API, but applies to Twitter's OAuth API in general.

1. That page only gives you **your** access token and access token secret to **your own** apps. This is fine if you don't need your app to be authenticated as any other users, so no need to request request tokens and no need to exchange the request token for access token, you just use your access token

   However, if you want to authenticate as other users, you will have to go through all the required steps, which is explained in short here:

   - You request the **request** token. It is only used for signing in, and cannot be used to access user's data. You will get the request token and request token secret. When requesting the request token, **you can specify a callback URL** which Twitter will send your users to when it is authenticated successfully.
   - You need to keep the request token and secret until the authentication is done.
   - After that, you redirect the user to `http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=` followed by OAuth token.
   - After the user signed in to Twitter and allowed your application, Twitter sends the user back to the callback URL.
   - You exchange the request token for the access token, and you can then discard the request token because you won't need it anymore.

   You can keep the access token as long as you need it. If you don't keep the access token, you will need to request the request token and exchange it for access token again, and your users will have to sign in again.

   So basically, if you are creating something that the user needs to sign in using Twitter, you need to do all the steps above to get the user signed in. If you are just using Twitter's API for yourself, you don't need the authentication step. **Use your access token.**
2. You can **check for the tweet's ID** by checking for the `id_str` key on the returned response.

   If the status isn't posted, Twitter will return an error object.
3. You can specify the **default** OAuth callback in the application settings page, which will be used when you don't explicitly specify a callback.

   This is required because if you somehow forget to or did not specify a callback URL, Twitter will still know where to redirect your users to.

   However, Twitter encourages that **you should explicitly specify a callback URL**. There are many benefit from using a callback URL, such as being able to specify any URLs as the callback. I used to benefit from this one because my Twitter client runs on two different domains, I could redirect the users back to the right place.

Comment: @Thai.. regarding your point 1 , it means we can run our application with any user without their authentication??

Comment: @Thai regarding point 3, i said which callback URL is to be followed by twitter application? i write both places a different Callback URL,

Comment: @diEcho 1. The user will have to sign in to Twitter and allow your application to access first before you can have that token. You use the token instead of their username and password. Once you have the token you can keep it as long as the user doesn't revoke access from your application.

Comment: @diEcho 3. The URL in your application code is more important than the registered one. If your code sends a callback URL, it will use the URL sent from your code. If not, it sends user to the registered one.

Comment: @diEcho And you need to put your ID in quotes as it is too big for PHP. `'id' => '32320907720523776'`

Comment: @thai i put id in quote but still nothing displayed... :(

Comment: @Thai 1. i know that user have to sign in , but my Question is that where that user's information is used after getting `access token`, means once we get `request token` from a user , will b forever untill he invoke the application

Comment: @diEcho Yes, but you use the access token, and not the request token.

Comment: @diEcho It is really strange that it does not show any error. Try checking your syntax.

Comment: @Thai yes, i m doing so...i just asked that why we always repeat this process .. even everything work great, but these are confusing concepts... but still we cant figure out the latest tweet

Comment: i have to check the answer but nothing is fully satisfactory answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Because we get AccessToken and Access Token Secret  only after we validate user with verifier .

The verifier is most important in OAuth process.So We need to send one request to generate 
  AccessToken and Access Token Secret .

After getting  AccessToken and Access Token Secret we can use it for time specified by user while allowing your Twitter application to allow access to his Info.it may be 1 day ,1 month like wise in LInkedin OAuth after that time the  AccessToken and Access Token Secret expires.........

Comment: i written in my question that.. access token & access token secret is already given when we create any application

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you do:

```
$temp = $connection->post( 'statuses/update', array('status' => 'some message got from textarea value' );
print_r($temp);
```

I would guess that would store the response (in json/xml) format in the $temp var. 
(To test twitter responses you can check http://dev.twitter.com/console)

The callback url that is defined in config.php will determine where it will be redirected. This is because this callback parameter was recently added to the twitter API. Before that you could only define the callback url on the App management section of twitter.com, this URL is the default url if no other url is defined.

Comment: i got below  result TwitterOAuth Object
(
    [http_code] => 200
    [last_api_call] => https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json
    [host] => https://api.twitter.com/1/
    [timeout] => 30
    [connecttimeout] => 30
    [ssl_verifypeer] => 
    [format] => json
    [decode_json] => 1
    [sha1_method] => OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 Object
        (
        )

    [consumer] => OAuthConsumer Object
        ([key] => [secret] => )

    [token] => OAuthConsumer Object
        ([key] => [secret] =>)

)

Comment: Does print_r($temp->response) do anything?

Comment: @diEcho hmm, I guess I don't know the Abraham API at all. You could try calling the $connection->post line with valid authentication in place and without valid authentication, perhaps the $temp response will be different. I think the 'http_code' response might be different if you aren't authenticated.