# How to sent user back to our website if he deny Twitter application to access?

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

i m using **Abraham twitteroauth** class for updating the twitter status, but i stuck in minor problem, please help me. myquestion is :

> if a user deny the access of
>   application, then how to navigate the
>   user back to our website ??

currently a user  click the 'sign in with twitter' button.then it goes to [twitter website](https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=M9WGecnopAzyCavdVfsdfsdfsdfsdfZSIGGYpP83Rg)

where its is being asked

#### An application would like to connect to your account Allow {application name }access?

and if user click on **Deny** button then it halts on [this link](https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize)
where this is displayed

> OK, you've denied {application name }
>   access to interact with your account!
>
> Feel free to find other applications
>   and find out what people are talking
>   about right now at Twitter.

so how do i sent user back to my website?? ask for code if required...

#### Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should just let the twitter website open in a new window or a new tab in the browser. That way the user never actually leaves your website.

Comment: @Geoffrey but i m not want to do that...is there no way if we deny the application access from same page?

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to catch events on a website that is not under your control. Maybe it would work if you load the twitter website in a frame on your web page. maybe then you could catch some events of that twitter page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users clicks "deny" you can't force them to redirect back to your site. There is no configuration that will do this. You will just have to hope the user clicks on your application name.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i seen some of application where user deny the access then automatically go back to main site... how does that possible then??

Comment: What application? I'll take a look at it and see what they are doing. I'm pretty sure to that what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: @abraham.. u r right...i checkd `twitpic`
(i think this is largest application of twitter ) also does not navigate back...

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does this automatically. I would make sure that everything on twitters side (specifically call back url) is set correctly. Once it is, and a user denies the request, it will send back to the request URL with a 'denied' $_GET key that you can use to key off of for a user message.

Comment: twitter not automatically redirecting, dats why i m asking here... tell me the code, where i have to put the condition that if user deny then go to this this url..?

Comment: where do i check/debug  `$_GET` variable??